# How to Access Prototype for value inside variable

Tags: javascript, prototype

I'm trying to access prototype for a value in variable.
For example :

```js
var myObjVar = {name : 's'};
var x = "myObjVar";
```

Here how to access prototype of `myObjVar` using `x`?

Its possible to access `myObjVar.prototype`

But I need to access through `x` ?

Comment: Why do you need that? In general it's not possible (fortunately)

Comment: @zerkms, in my scenario, myObjVar is static(it may ot may not present), Dynamically i have to check the myObjVar prototype is present or sent

Comment: Well, it's not "why" you need that. It's still an awkward solution for some problem.

Answer (score 0):

A doubly ugly solution is using `eval` and the non-standard `__proto__` property:

```
eval(x).__proto__
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the object belongs to global scope:

```
window["myObjVar"].constructor.prototype
```

Otherwise use eval() (NOT RECOMMENDED!):

```
eval("myObjVar").constructor.prototype
```